# Multiple Ajax scripts in page

Tags: jquery, ajax

It maybe a stupid coding issue, but I have googled since a couple days, tried to rebuild my code a few times, and I always end up in the same situation.

My page structure is something like that:

/controller/

```
   |--Menu_Controller.php
```

/pages/

```
   |--ContentA.php

   |--ContentB.php
```

/index.php

I have an ajax script that calls and refreshes the Content area in my Index.php

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language = "javascript">
    (function($)
    {
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var mid = "<?php echo $MainMenu;?>";
            var sid = "<?php echo $SubMenu;?>";
            $.ajaxSetup(
                {
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {mid:mid,sid:sid,},
                });
            var $container = $("#Content");
            $container.load("controller/Menu_Controller.php");
            var refreshId = setInterval(function()
            {
                $container.load('controller/Menu_Controller.php');
            }, 5000);
        });
    })(jQuery);

</script>
```

And in my loaded content, I have a form which should triggers another ajax script when I hit the submit button.

```js
<script>
    // Attach a submit handler to the form
    $( "#searchForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
        alert('Test');
        });
    });
</script>
```

But only the one or the other ajax works :(
I'm sure I placed the code maybe at the wrong spots or something stupid.

Thanks for your help!
Alex

Comment: You don't need to use `$.ajaxSetup()` to set parameters for `$.load()`, it takes an optional data argument.

Comment: What should I use instead of $.ajaxSetup()? If I want to post data to my content area? In my case the Menu ID

Comment: `$.load("url", {mid:mid, sid: sid})`

Comment: Thanks Barmar! I have changed it, but the issue stays the same, the other ajax script doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "one or the other ajax works"? It looks like they're both the same.

Comment: In my content, I have another script which should open a modal window, and it is triggered by the submit button, but this only works if I delete the code from the .load script

Comment: Do you have any IDs that are duplicated between the two contents? IDs have to be unique.

Comment: I don't exactly know, what ID's you mean, I only have one content and I have 2 files where I placed JS Script Code. And just one or the other is working, but not both.

Comment: I mean is `id="searchForm"` duplicated in both contents that are loaded with AJAX?

Comment: Well in this test it was, but I also tried it with class instead of ID, and it is the same result as well.

Comment: Not sure what I should be looking for there. Clicking on Edit opens the modal, and the C button closes it.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some more google search. I believe my issue is event delegate, and that the ajax load changes the code in the background. So far I understand the issue and I have modified my code several times, but my result is still the same. After reloading (ajax load) my content, the form submit in my content doesn't work.

Here is, what I changed so far:

load/relaod code

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language = "javascript">
    (function($)
    {
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var mid = "<?php echo $MainMenu;?>";
            var sid = "<?php echo $SubMenu;?>";
            var $container = $("#Content");
            //$container.load("controller/Menu_Controller.php",{mid:mid,sid:sid}); // Initial load for testing deactivated!
            var refreshId = setInterval(function()
            {
                $container.load("controller/Menu_Controller.php",{mid:mid,sid:sid});
            }, 10000);
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

show modal window

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language = "javascript">
    $( window ).load(function() {
        $('#Content').on('click','.show',function(event) {
            $(".backdrop").show( "fade", { direction: "left"  }, 150 );
            $(".modal-window").show( "fade", {direction: "left" }, 700 );
        });

        $(".close").click(function(){
            $(".backdrop").hide( "fade", { direction: "left"  }, 700 );
            $(".modal-window").hide( "fade", { direction: "left"  }, 700 );
        });
    });
</script>
```

submit form data and display in modal

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language = "javascript">
    $("form.myform").on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action
        var request_method = $(this).attr("method");
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        
        $.ajax({
            url : 'include/modal_post_receiver.php',
            type: request_method,
            data : form_data
        }).done(function(data){ //
            $("#modal").html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any support.

Alex